# Joins and classifying spaces in the category of compactly generated spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles

In Milnor's Construction of Universal Bundles, II, he defines $E_nG$ by repeated
joins of $G$ with itself, but he has to use the `strong topology' on the join instead
of the everyday topology that results from viewing the join as the 
 pushout of  $X\times CY \gets X\times Y\to CX \times Y$.  He makes use of the strong 
topology in verifying that the orbit map $E_nG \to B_nG$ is a   bundle.

My question is:  if we restrict our attention to weak Hausdorff compactly generated
spaces, is the strong topology  needed?

Comment: @Jeff: This is not an answer but kind of echoes the problem for joins. In my book now available as "Topology and Groupoids" (amazon, see my web page) I gave an account of the initial topology on joins, and it is convenient for mah purposes. For example it is associative; it is good for maps into it. The identification type topology is of course good for maps out of it. But I never managed to prove they were equivalent in compactly generated spaces. Am I missing something simple? 